# what is wrong with this preg_replace command?

Tags: php, preg-replace, eval

I have these codes:

```
$string = 'Hello [*tt();*], how are you today?';
preg_match("/\[\*(.*?)\*\]/",$string,$match);
$func = $match[1];
$d = eval($func);
$newstring = preg_replace("/\[\*(.*?)\*\]/",$d,$string);
echo $newstring;

function tt() {
     return 'test';
}
```

I think they reach my mean from them. I want to replace tt(); with its output.I expected it works but tt(); replace with nothing(null string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned.

```
$d = eval("return $func");
```

`eval` should be used with caution. See [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php/951868#951868)

Comment: wow,thank you.why is eval bad? because it can run a text as php code? I think using eval is bad when the text is getting from user.but in my case the text is define by admin directly in database.

Comment: Updated my answer, to be more informative than "eval is bad" :D

Answer (score 1):

`$d = eval($func);`

should be

`eval('$d = ' . $func);`

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions are fine. Your problem is with the `eval()` statement. It does not return a value like you expect. The assignment needs to happen in the `eval()` as well.

```
function tt() {
     return 'test';
}

$string = 'Hello [*tt();*], how are you today?';
preg_match("/\[\*(.*?)\*\]/",$string,$match);
$func = $match[1];
eval('$d = ' . $func);
$newstring = preg_replace("/\[\*(.*?)\*\]/",$d,$string);
echo $newstring;
```